# "Network request failed" when request to .NET web service with url port other than 80

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch

I'm writing a React Native app to run on Android phone. In the app, I'll fetch data from a .NET web service on the local network (using port 8085).

When I test the app on emulator, the fetch run as expected. But when I run it on my phone, the fetch always fail with error **Network request failed** (the server and the phone is on the same LAN).

I've try to change the port to 80, and the app run as expected on my phone.

I also turn off all others website in IIS, but the same problem with port <> 80.

I've do some research on Google (many time it redirect me to SO and Github) but with no luck.

Below is my fetch:

```
  _getValue1 = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.165:8085/index.aspx/GetValue1', {
        body: JSON.stringify({ Usr: ... }),
        headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        method: 'POST',
      });

      const json = await response.json();

      // do things with the json result
    }
    catch (err) {
      // always go here if run on real phone with url port other than 80
    }
  }
```

Anyone has experience with this problem please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is something called firewall, which may be blocking the port. As you are using IIS, so here is the link to enable port. https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html

Just enable your required port. I hope, this would help.

Comment: After I allow incoming of 8085 port in the firewall, everything works as expected. Thanks for the help of Shrivastav in the comment.